# How to choose operator precedence?

Tags: language-agnostic, operators, operator-precedence, idris

In Idris, you can define operators using `infix`, `infixl` or `infixr`, followed by the precedence of the operators then a list of operators, like

```
infixl 8 +, -
```

I imagine you can do this in other languages too.

I know what effect precedence has, but how do I choose what precedence to give my operators? What problems might I encounter if I initially choose a precedence that's too high or low?

Answer (score 0):

For most languages the operator precedence table is already defined by the language itself.

Following one of these would guarantee that your code/language is up to what's considered standard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence